# combining multiple columns of multiple tables in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I have two tables :
Student_Info and Student_Academics

Following are the columns in Student_Info : Id , Name , Gender , Address // Id is primary key
Following are the columns in Student_Academics : SerialNo , Id , Branch , Grade // Id is foreign key

I want to count number of students whose gender is female and branch is CS .

I tried using join queries but it does not give the required information.

Comment: Show the table definitions, data, query, output and desired output that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
select count(1)
  from Student_Info SI, Student_Academics SA
 where si.id = sa.id
   and si.gender = 'female'
   and sa.Branch = 'CS';
```